# Kafka connect- SpoolDir source connector not showing up

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I tried to create a Kafka Connect SpoolDir source connector using a Rest API call. After starting the zookeeper and Kafka server, and starting the worker using `kafka/bin/connect-distributed.sh dir-distributed.properties`, I made the following API call from Postman:

```
POST http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

```
{
    "name": "csv-source-orders",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topic": "orders",
        "input.file.pattern":"^orders.*.csv$",
        "input.path":"/Users/ivij/temp/source",
        "finished.path":"/Users/ivij/temp/finished",
        "error.path":"/Users/ivij/temp/error",
        "halt.on.error": "false",
        "csv.separator.char":"01",
        "value.schema":"{\"name\":\"com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.model.Value\",\"type\":\"STRUCT\",\"isOptional\":false,\"fieldSchemas\":{\"order_id\":{\"type\":\"INT64\",\"isOptional\":false},\"customer_id\":{\"type\":\"INT64\",\"isOptional\":false},\"order_ts\":{\"type\":\"STRING\",\"isOptional\":false},\"product\":{\"type\":\"STRING\",\"isOptional\":false},\"order_total_usd\":{\"type\":\"STRING\",\"isOptional\":false}}}",
        "key.schema":"{\"name\":\"com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.model.Key\",\"type\":\"STRUCT\",\"isOptional\":false,\"fieldSchemas\":{\"order_id\":{\"type\":\"INT64\",\"isOptional\":false}}}",
        "csv.first.row.as.header": "true",
        "flush.size": "100",
        "rotate.interval.ms": "1000"
    }
}
```

The response status is `201 Created` with a message that a new resource was created. But in the body of the response, the tasks field is empty :

```
    "tasks": [],
    "type": "source"
```

- When I try to check the status of connectors or list the connectors using `GET localhost:8083/connectors/` the response received is `[]`.
- I also tried to list the topics being created on port 8083 (to check if the "orders" topic in API json was being created), but that gave an OutOfMemory error. 
  Is the connector being created? How can I resolve this?

Edit: Following is the 'dir-distributed.properties' file:

```
#connect-distributed.properties

bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
group.id=connect-cluster-a

rest.port=8083

schema.generation.enabled=true
schema.generation.value.name=schemavalue
schema.generation.key.name=schemakey

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=1

config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=1

status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=1

offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=.../kafka-connect-spooldir/target/kafka-connect-target/usr/share/kafka-connect/
```

Comment: What do you mean "list topics created on port 8083"? Where did you see the OOM?

Comment: I ran `kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:8083` from the terminal, which gave this error.

Comment: 8083 is not a bootstrap server, it's a REST API. Did you mean 9092?

Comment: Oh, I did this wrong then. I was unaware of this. Where should the "orders" topic be created then?

Comment: In Kafka...? You'll need to use the correct port. And I just said what it was (by default)

Comment: Notice in your config file - bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

Comment: i checked for the topic using `kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092` too, but it wasn't there. Does this mean that the connector creation is failing and that is why neither the topic nor the connector instance show up?

Comment: This is what i receive after the api call : HTTP/1.1 201 Created       
Date: Tue, 15 Sep 2020 14:38:52 GMT.    
Location: http://localhost:8083/connectors/csv-source-new

Comment: 201 is the POST call, so it's created. You can look at the server logs or status endpoint for any errors

Comment: The only error I am able to catch is "Found configuration for connector 'connector-csv-source-new' in wrong format: class org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaConfigBackingStore:586)". Can you please help me with this? I could not find the mistake in configurtion

Comment: Try changing the value for `config.storage.topic`

Comment: Thanks a lot @OneCricketeer! I was able to resolve it by deleting the old storage,offset and config topics and recreate new ones with partitions=1. Not sure why that worked, guessing maybe because the number of partitions in server properties was set to 1.

Comment: The error you were getting indicates there was some bad data in the topic that it couldn't deserialize

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer I have similar problem (Found configuration for connector ...), I double checked and the three topics kafka-connect-config kafka-connect-offset kafka-connect-status has replication and partition of 1. What else I can check?
idk is it matter, but I'm using kubernetes and cp-kafka:5.5.0, cp-kafka-connect-5.5.0 and cp-schema-registry:5.5.0.

Comment: @GeorgiStoyanov As mentioned, the topic contains bad data

Comment: @OneCricketeer i deleted them, created new one, made the query and again it's the same result. I have only 1 message in the config connector.class�com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirJsonSourceConnector$input.file.pattern(checklist_login.json▒finished.path4/dependency/json/processedtasks.maxname,kafka-connect-spooldir
topitesterror.path,/dependency/json/errorinput.path/  and 0 messages in the other two topics

Comment: @GeorgiStoyanov The contents of each of those topics should be JSON, so any � symbol indicates the Converter for the internal topics are incorrect

Comment: @OneCricketeer thank you so much!! It took me some time, but I found that in the configuration we had  internal.key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter. When i made it JSONConverter everything started working perfectly.

Comment: @GeorgiStoyanov Those properties are deprecated, so you should be able to just remove them, anyway